# How do I read the header from the inFile and write the header to the outFile? (python 3)

Tags: python, pandas

I used next in the file read in order to parse the data not the header row, so read avoided the first row altogether. How can I pick up the header on the read (but not parse the header row) then write the header on the write operation?

The real data set that I want to do this operation on is 30 cols and 80k rows so I was trying to get this done in one read operation.

Test data:

```
date, animal, color
3/14/2015, cat, blue
3/24/2015, dog, green
```

Code:

```
from dateutil.parser import *
import csv

with open('testin.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as inFile, open('testout.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outFile:
    exampleReader = csv.reader(inFile)
    next(exampleReader, 1)
    exampleData = list(exampleReader)
    exampleWriter = csv.writer(outFile)
    # print a few to see what it's doing
    print('the list', exampleData)
    for item in exampleData:
        item[0] = str(parse(item[0])) # converting date format for sqlite
        del item[2] # dropping column that is not needed
        print('date corrected', item) 
        exampleWriter.writerow(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

i would use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) for such an amount of data:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = """\
date, animal, color, junk
3/14/2015, cat, blue, aaa
3/24/2015, dog, green, bbb
"""
num_cols = 4
all_cols = set(range(num_cols))
skip_cols = set([2,3])

# replace `io.StringIO(data)` with the CSV filename    
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data),
                 sep=',',
                 skipinitialspace=True,
                 parse_dates=[0],
                 usecols=(all_cols - skip_cols))
print(df)

# save DF as CSV file
df.to_csv('/path/to/new.csv', index=False)

# save DF to SQLite DB
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///my_db.sqlite')
df.to_sql('my_table', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

Example:

```
In [150]: data = """\
   .....: date, animal, color, junk
   .....: 3/14/2015, cat, blue, aaa
   .....: 3/24/2015, dog, green, bbb
   .....: """

In [151]: num_cols = 4

In [152]: all_cols = set(range(num_cols))

In [153]: skip_cols = set([2,3])

In [154]: df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data),
   .....:                  sep=',',
   .....:                  skipinitialspace=True,
   .....:                  parse_dates=['date'],
   .....:                  usecols=(all_cols - skip_cols))

In [155]: print(df)
        date animal
0 2015-03-14    cat
1 2015-03-24    dog
```

Comment: This is really great - especially the SQL generation. The only thing that differs from the OP's current CSV output is that the dates are formatted without the time part (00:00:00), but the time is probably not wanted by the OP anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Write the header before processing the rest of the input file:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
import csv

with open('testin.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as inFile, open('testout.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outFile:
    exampleReader = csv.reader(inFile)
    header = next(exampleReader)

    exampleWriter = csv.writer(outFile)
    del header[2]    # drop the column from the header
    exampleWriter.writerow(header)

    for row in exampleReader:
        row[0] = parse(row[0]) # converting date format for sqlite
        del row[2] # dropping column that is not needed
        print('date corrected', row) 
        exampleWriter.writerow(row)
```

I've rearranged things a bit, however, the main point is to read the header into a variable with `next()`, drop the unwanted column from the header, and then write it to the output file. Then the rest of the input file is processed.

One important point is that the rest of the input file is processed line-by-line in a for loop. It is not necessary to read upfront the entire file into a list when you can just iterate over it.

You could also use a generator expression to efficiently write the rows:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
import csv

def process_row(row, is_header=False):
    if not is_header:
        row[0] = parse(row[0])
    del row[2]
    return row

with open('data', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as inFile, open('testout.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outFile:
    exampleReader = csv.reader(inFile)
    header = next(exampleReader)

    exampleWriter = csv.writer(outFile)
    exampleWriter.writerow(process_row(header, is_header=True))

    exampleWriter.writerows(process_row(row) for row in exampleReader)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do as follows. I have omitted the `print` lines to keep it short.

```
from dateutil.parser import *
import csv

with open('testin.csv', 'r') as inFile, open('testout.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    exampleReader = csv.reader(inFile)
    headers = next(exampleReader)
    exampleWriter = csv.writer(outFile)
    exampleWriter.writerow(headers)
    for item in exampleReader:
        item[0] = str(parse(item[0])) # converting date format for sqlite
        del item[2] # dropping column that is not needed
        exampleWriter.writerow(item)
```

*Do not use `exampleData = list(exampleReader)` in your production code. It will eat all you memory.*